# Updating WordPress 3.6 to 3.7 via admin area on Nginx VPS hangs and fails

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress, php-fpm

So I have a few WordPress sites running on my VPS (Ubuntu 12.10, Nginx, php-fpm 5.4)

The sites are all on seperate vhosts and use their own config files (albeit similar to each other) and vary in complexity. One is very simple and uses minimal plugins.

When I try to update core on any site via the admin area I click the "Update Now" button (which should run the script in `wp-admin/update-core.php` the page hangs for a minute or two before going to a blank admin page (i.e. the wp-admin menu bars and header bar are there but there is no content in the body of the page). Visiting another admin page via the still menu bar reveals that the core has not been updated.

Checking the error log I see this entry:

> 2013/10/29 23:20:48 [error] 9384#0: *5318248 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: --.---.--.---, server: www.mysite.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-core-upgrade HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.com", referrer: "http://mysite.com/wp-admin/update-core.php"

This didn't happen in the past on older updates and the rest of the site including updating plugins works fine.

Any ideas? Could it be as simple as a time-out error? I find that unlikely as the server should munch though a wp upgrade in seconds.

Comment: Try to strace a PHP upgrade process to find what could be causing the issue, could it be a network related timeout, or there is something else in play.

Comment: I don't think it's network related as the rest of the site works fine and updating plugins works too. How would I trace a php upgrade process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress update is a slow process.

Add

```
request_terminate_timeout = 300s
```

to your www.conf

You need to increase fastcgi read timeout in your nginx vhost file

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 300s
```

Also, check your execution time in php ini, or redefine it in www.conf for php-fpm

```
php_admin_value[execution_time] = 300
```

Comment: Can we clarify which www.conf we are talking about. I am still confused as to what config files apply to what. I thought nginx.conf is Nginx's and php-fpm's is called php-fpm.conf...

Comment: OK I increased the timeout in the vhost config file, went to update and it updated in about 2 seconds. Very strange, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Two things you'd want to check with WP updates from my experience.

- network problems, do a netstat on server to see if there are some
  connections from php process that is updating and an external server.
  some servers are slower than others.
- limited number of php-fpm workers, I've seen WP updates calling themselves via HTTP so it locks
  all available workers.

try:

- php-fpm's slowlog
- higher nginx's side timeout on fastcgi
- strace is the best thing next to nutella. use it.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the slowlog. When I edit `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and uncomment the slowlog lines I get a 502 bad gateway error